# SharedPreferances ( or other memory ) among different apps?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

What do you think would be the best way to make shared memory space between two or more apps?
For example, I'll have a main app and other apps, containing sort of different plugins for the main app.  Therefor the main app should be able to read data from additional apps.

Of course, the simplest way would be to make a folder on the sd memory and store data there, but I don't want the user to have access to the raw data, as well sd memory is not always available.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android provides the `Content Providers` mechanism for data sharing. A `Content Provider` is an interface to your application's database, that allows other application to access your data. This is the preferred solution of data sharing between two applications problem. You can read more about `Content Providers` [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Depends a lot on what data you want to share. ContentProvider (lot's of text and numbers), sd-card (binary data like images etc), SharedPreferences (a bit text/numbers), or even exotic places to store data like external webservices (if you want the app to have consistent data over several devices)